# PHP switch falling though issue

Tags: php

Code:

```
switch ($_GET['operation']) {
    case "professionist":
    case "company":
    case "student":
        echo "ok<br>";

    case "professionist":
        echo "inprofessionist<br>";
        break;

    case "company":
        echo "incompany<br>";
        break;

    default:
        echo "Meh!<br>";
        break;
}
```

My goal is to execute some (common to professionist/company/student) code first, and then execute the rest of the code depending on the operation...

The problem is that the first 3 cases works perfectly, but then, if for example the operation is "company", the switch go on "professionist" case, what i'm doing wrong? How can improve that? Thanks in advance...

Comment: You forgot a break before case "professionist"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how switch works. If you always need to print "ok" then move it outside switch:

```
$op = $_GET["operation"];

if (in_array($op, array("professionist", "company"))) {
   echo "ok<br>";
}

switch ($op) {
    case "professionist":
        echo "inprofessionist<br>";
        break;

    case "company":
        echo "incompany<br>";
        break;

    default:
        echo "Meh!<br>";
        break;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, just something to note: `in_array($needle, Array $haystack)`

Answer (score 2):

Only the first `case` with a given value will ever be targeted by a `switch`. (And in fact, a `switch` only ever goes to a single case per execution - fallthough just lets you have multiple cases share some code, but only one of them is what's actually triggered.)

Thus, it doesn't make sense to have multiple `case`es with the same value that they're looking for - a `switch` statement isn't the same thing as a series of independent `if`s; it's a mapping of jump targets.

Essentially, let's say you have a switch like this:

```
w;                               // 001
switch ($foo) {                  // 002
  case 'a':
     w;                          // 003
  case 'b':
     x;                          // 004
     break;                      // 005
  case 'c':
     y;                          // 006
}
z;                               // 007
```

What actually winds up effectively happening is that you get some code effectively like this (note: highly simplified from how this actually works):

```
001  v
002  jump based on $foo: [a -> 003, b -> 004, c -> 006]
003  w
004  x
005  jump to 007
006  y
007  z
```

and then that program just gets run from top to bottom.

- In the case where `$foo` is 'a', it jumps to 003 and runs from there, which means that it winds up doing `v,jump,w,x,z` in total.
- In the case where `$foo` is 'b', it jumps to 004 and runs from there, which means that it winds up doing `v,jump,x,z` in total.
- In the case where `$foo` is 'c', it jumps to 006 and runs from there, which means that it winds up doing `v,jump,y,z` in total.